# Finding parametrization of $xz^2=xy^2+y^3$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am doing a problem on geometry and was stuck at one step. I want to parametrize the curve $xz^2=xy^2+y^3$ using two parameters $s,t$. But I cannot figure it out. I am wondering if this is a famous curve or if anyone has any thoughts?

Comment: How about $s=y, t=z$ ?

Comment: Btw, it's a surface not a curve, you will need two parameters if that was the problem.

Comment: @OlivierMassicot: one homogeneous polynomial in three variables defines a curve in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^{2}.$

Comment: From the perspective of algebraic geometry, one way to do this is to consider lines through the unique singular point: these form a $\Bbb P^1$, and we get a unique other intersection by Bezout. Try it yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=s$ and $z=t$, then $x=\frac{s^3}{t^2-s^2}$.

But observe that when $t^2=s^2$, then from the equation given we get $s^3=0 \implies s=0$. Thus for all $s,t \neq 0$, the above parametrization can work.

Comment: You can also rephrase this by letting $y=s(t^2-s^2)$, $z=t(t^2-s^2)$, and $x=s^3$, which makes it more obvious it's a rational parameterization (a map from $\Bbb P^1$).

Comment: Thanks! And yes, this is actually the real problem I am solving: find the rational parametrization!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{z^2}{y^2}= 1+\dfrac{y}{x} \tag1 $$

Let $(s,c)$ be short for $ (\sin,\cos)$ for any argument, say $t$

$$ x= c^2,\; y=s^2\; \tag2 $$

Plug into (1)
$$z^2= \dfrac{s^4}{c^2}$$

simplify
$$ \pm z= \dfrac{1}{c}-c \tag3$$
Take positive sign

Comment: by choosing $x=\cos^2 t$, aren't you restricting to the case where $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: No. The parametrization does not change because  $x$ is an even *cosine function*  of the parameter. $t$. That even when $(x=-c^2,y=-s^2, z= \pm s^2/c) $ 3D embedding remains the same.